# Сообщение об ошибке выводится кракозябрами

Tags: windows, кодировка, postgresql, golang

При наличии ошибки в ходе выполнения программы в консоль выкидывается сообщение, содержащее текст на русском, который отображается кракозябрами:

> `2012/03/19 18:47:43 
>     Severity: ╨Ю╨и╨Ш╨С╨Ъ╨Р
>     Code: 42P07
>     Message: ╨╛╤В╨╜╨╛╤И╨╡╨╜╨╕╨╡ "users" ╤Г╨╢╨╡ ╤Б╤Г╤Й╨╡╤Б╤В╨▓╤Г╨╡╤В`

Как это исправить?

P.S. Используется обычная установка PostgreSQL 9.1 с опциями по умолчанию на Windows XP SP 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

По умолчанию в командной строке Windows используется кодировка CP866 (унаследованная еще от DOS). Ваш интерпретатор Go пишет в современной кодировке UTF-8. Проверить это можно, например, в [декодере Лебедева](http://www.artlebedev.ru/tools/decoder/advanced/), скопировав текст в форму и нажав кнопку "расшифровать".

Следовательно, есть два способа. Первый - перехватывать текст и смотреть в программе, понимающей UTF-8. Вы его как раз изобрели ;)

Второй способ - научить командную строку разговаривать в кодировке UTF-8. Если работаете в cmd или PowerShell, нужно выполнить такой трюк: в контекстном меню на заголовке выбрать настройки, а там - шрифт Lucida Console (он поддерживает кириллический набор знаков для UTF-8). Теперь можно сменить кодировку командой `chcp 65001` и радоваться.

P.S. Давно это делал последний раз, возможно, изменилось что-то, попробуйте.

Answer (score 0):

Нашел решение в обход. Запускаю программу с выводом ошибок не в консоль, а в лог:

```
app.exe 2>app.html
```

После чего смотрю `app.html` в Хроме. Все по-русски.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте следующую инструкцию, чтобы изменить кодировку по умолчанию для всех командлетов, имеющих параметр Encoding в PowerShell:

```
$PSDefaultParameterValues['*:Encoding'] = 'utf8'
```