# PostgreSQL русская кодировка

Tags: postgresql

Добрый день. При работе с PostgreSQL выводится нечитаемый закодированный текст в cmd:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробовал менять шрифт в cmd **Lucida Console** и менять кодировку в cmd

```
chcp 1251
```

Также, исходя из данного совета [в похожем вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/91429/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D0%B1-%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B7%D1%8F%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8), менял кодировку на 65001

```
chcp 65001
```

Но это не дало результата. Подскажите, что еще можно попробовать сделать?

Comment: Для pgsql делаю так `pgsql -b ... 2>err.txt` Потом открываю err.txt в notepad++ и там подбираю кодировку такую, чтобы текст отображался нормальными буквами. Если утилита не умеет выводить ошибки в stderr, то так `dropdb ... > err.txt`. Но при этом вы не увидите приглашение ввести пароль.

Comment: В консоли `pgsql` я ввожу `\! chcp 1251` и в данной консоли - `pgsql` все нормально отображается. Если в консоли `cmd` я ввожу `dropdb -U postgres test123 > err.txt` то вместо приглашения на ввод пароля, получаю "Отказано в доступе"

Comment: Получилось создать текстовой файл с ошибками с помощью `dropdb -U postgres test123 2>test.txt` дальше можно декодировать либо через notepad++ или через декодер Лебедева.

Comment: Насколько я помню, консоль windows по умолчанию в кодировке Windows 866. Я вывел в err.txt, как выше советовал Sergey, открыл в Sublime и поменял на 866, все нормально читается.

Answer (score 1):

Для общего понимания:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/multibyte.html

А по поводу кодировки я бы посоветовал использовать только UTF-8 он не имеет ограничений по языку.

Comment: Насколько я помню `chcp 65001` это и есть UTF-8, как писал в вопросе - это не помогло.